# What are the powers of the Golden Lance?

Tags: hanna-barbera, galtar-and-the-golden-lance

In the H-B cartoon *Galtar & The Golden Lance* the titular weapon is a twin sword/connected lance that seems capable of various forms of magic.

Is there any canon list of everything the lance can do, its origins and its limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point the only canonical answer would be what was shown in the 21 episodes.

Allegedly the Golden Lance combined with the Sacred Shield renders the wielder completely invincible.

On its own, the Golden Lance has discriminating powers similar to Mjolnir in that if it is held by an "unworthy" hand the hilt will release "The Fury of The Golden Lance." Also, according to the hermit if the wielder ever uses it for evil, it will turn on them and destroy them.

Each blade can shoot an energy beam at an opponent by pointing it at them.

[image: Energy Beam]

Also like Mjolnir, if you cross the two blades it shoots a bolt of lightning at your opponent.

[image: Golden Lance]

And once again like Mjolnir, the lances can be twirled to allow you to fly toward your opponent. I don't know the range as I have not seen Galtar fly through the air.

[image: Flying with the swords]

The power of the energy beam can be magnified by striking a sword on a metal surface, releasing an immense energy beam.

[image: Magnifying the energy beam]

Each of the 21 episodes we seem to learn yet another power of this weapon. Because the show was cancelled before the final battle, a comprehensive list cannot be made.

Comment: Thank you. I believe we saw him fly in the episode _The Silver Sword,_ but it was only a short distance as Galtar had fallen off a cliff wile fighting Tormack with his newly minted cursed weapon.